# Cannot mount external drives or flash drives

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, mount

I tried multiple file systems and multiple devices, none of them will mount. I also tried looking for `fsck` (not running), resetting the NVRAM (and restarting the Mac of course) and it still doesn't work. It shows up correctly in the Disk Utility, however it stays unmounted (even if I click mount). Is there anything else I can do? What might be wrong? FYI I did check the [following thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193239/usb-flash-drive-not-mounting-os-x) (although my problem is a bit different) and tried these solutions, didn't work.

[image]

**UPDATE**
As requested by the comment, I ran the following:

```
diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            ClickShare             *23.5 MB    disk2
```

Comment: In Terminal, what is the output of the following command? `diskutil list disk2` Copy the output from Terminal and paste it into your answer.

Comment: @user3439894 Updated the question as requested.

Comment: I've never seen a 23.5 MB USB Flash drive and there is information missing in the output that I'd expect to see. How was this USB Flash Drive formatted?

Comment: It's a ClickShare device (FAT16), 23.5 MB is valid. But I have the same symptoms with my external HDD.

Comment: And also another pendrive that's not a specialised device.

Comment: You could try Mountain, a mac app that mounts and unmounts volumes. It has always worked for me but its probably the same as your unix commands. Mountain can be found here: https://www.appgineers.de/mountain/

Comment: Is that “ClickShare” device supposed to be able to be read by a Mac?  Does it have data on it you donn’t mind losing?

Comment: @Allan Yes, but you're missing the point - none of the other external drives work, either...